# opencv findHomography error: (-215) CV_IS_MASK_ARR(mask) &&

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm recieving this error

> error: (-215) CV_IS_MASK_ARR(mask) && CV_IS_MAT_CONT(mask->type) && (mask->rows == 1 || mask->cols == 1) && mask->rows*mask->cols == count in function cvFindHomography

from this code:

```
std::vector<Point2f> dstPoints(4);
dstPoints[0].x=1;
dstPoints[1].x=3;
dstPoints[2].x=1;
dstPoints[3].x=3;

dstPoints[0].y=0;
dstPoints[1].y=0;
dstPoints[2].y=2;
dstPoints[3].y=2;

std::vector<Point2f> srcPoints(4);
srcPoints[0].x=5;
srcPoints[1].x=6;
srcPoints[2].x=5;
srcPoints[3].x=7;

srcPoints[0].y=0;
srcPoints[1].y=0;
srcPoints[2].y=5;
srcPoints[3].y=5;

Mat floorHomog = findHomography(srcPoints,dstPoints);
```

and I have no idea why. The homography should be solveable with 4 points.
Thanks!

Comment: My code works on another machine, so it must be something in my opencv setup.

Comment: try calling the function with all parameters: findHomography(srcPoints, dstPoints, 0, 0, cv::Mat() ), it may help